# Based on Table 1 value, find the both duplicate value from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1

```
+--------+--------+
| Mem Id | Loc Id |
+--------+--------+
|    123 |      4 |
|    345 |      5 |
|   6245 |      9 |
|   3521 |      8 |
+--------+--------+
```

Table 2 and 3

```
+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------------+--------+-------+
| Mem Id | Loc Id | Member  | address |      city      | state  |  zip  |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------------+--------+-------+
|   6245 |      9 | XYZ     |    3524 | New york city  | NY     | 10456 |
|    564 |     15 | Medical |    1276 | The Bronx      | NY     | 10456 |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------------+--------+-------+

+--------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
| Mem Id | Loc Id | Member | address |   city    | state  |  zip  |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
|   6245 |      9 | XYZ    |    3524 | The Bronx | NY     | 10456 |
|   5689 |     52 | Boca   |     587 | The Bronx | NY     | 10456 |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+--------+---------+----------------+--------+-------+
| Mem Id | Loc Id | Member | address |      city      | state  |  zip  |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+----------------+--------+-------+
|   6245 |      9 | XYZ    |    3524 | New york city  | NY     | 10456 |
|   6245 |      9 | XYZ    |    3524 | The Bronx      | NY     | 10456 |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+----------------+--------+-------+

select * from [Table1] t1 
inner join [Table2] t2 on t1.[Location ID]=t2.[Location ID] and t1.[Member ID]=t2.[Member ID]
inner join [Table3] t3 on t1.[Location ID]=t3.[Location ID] and t1.[Member ID]=t3.[Member ID]
```

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: I need to see only the result table from tables 1, 2, 3. THE query I wrote is not working as expected.

Comment: [Edit] your question to clarify that. And if you add your sample data as DDL/DML (create temp table, insert into temp table) people can help you faster.

Comment: "Not working as expected" will not help us help you.  Please describe what is the "not expected" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables 2 and 3 seem to have the same structure, so you can use `union all` on them.  You seem to want records that overlap in the two tables, so that would seem to be:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from table3 t3
              where t3.[Location ID] = t2.[Location ID] and t3.[Member ID] = t2.[Member ID]
             )
union all
select t3.*
from table3 t3
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t3.[Location ID] = t2.[Location ID] and t3.[Member ID] = t2.[Member ID]
             );
```

You can further limit this to overlaps in `table1`, but that doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Perfect. :) Thank you so much for your quick help @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want.  From your example, this could be the solution.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table2
    WHERE [Mem Id] = t.[Mem Id]
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table3
    WHERE [Mem Id] = t.[Mem Id]
)
```